# AngularJS [Slim Framework] two index.php file in two different folders

Tags: php, angularjs

Connecting to the slim framework by angularjs like that

**app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('DatabaseFactory', function ($http) {
    return {
        getData: function () {
            return $http.get("app/api/getData");
        }
```

**api/index.php**

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/getData', function() {
     //WORKS GREAT
});
```

and it work great but this

**other.js**

```
app.factory('UsersFactory', function($http) {
return{
    getProfile: function(){
        return $http.get("app/api/users/getUser");
    }
}
```

**api/users/index.php**

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/getUser', function() {
     //DON'T WORK ERROR 404!!!
});
```

and return me error 404 file not found

FOLDERS:

api/Slim/other file

api/index.php

api/users/index.php

Please for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$app->get('/users/getUser', function() {

});
```

Should be this

Comment: i wrote this and still don't work maybe users/index can't see Slim folder

Comment: its something to do with your folder structure